# How to render block in plugin

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, template, plugin

I have an plugin with after method, that should append piece of html to return.

I think that the html shoul be in some template block. Is there a way to render block from plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: which class are you use for pluginization?

Comment: I'm extending \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\PrintOrder\Invoice class. (though i'm not sure, that's what are you asking for)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `LayoutInterface` for block creating.

```
/**
 * @param Invoice $subject
 * @param $result
 * @return string
 */
public function afterGetItemHtml(\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\PrintOrder\Invoice $subject, $result)
{
    $renderer = $subject->getLayout()
        ->createBlock(MyCustomBlock::class);

    return $result . $renderer->toHtml();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will helpful my answer.

I added plugin for **Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View**

Will override method - **execute()**

Get block by name - and return in json (for my case).

```
public function afterExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View $subject, $result)
    {
        $isAjax = $this->_request->getParam('isAjax', null);

        if (!is_null($isAjax)) {
            $block = $result->renderResult($subject->getResponse());
            $layout = $block->getLayout();

            $responseData = [];

            if ($layout->hasElement('main.content')) {
                $mainContent = $layout->renderElement('main.content');
                $responseData['main'] = $mainContent;
            }

            $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $resultJson->setData($responseData);
            return $resultJson;
        }

        return $result;
    }
```